# Google colab: printing in child processes

Tags: python, printing, google-colaboratory

I can't see any output in a google colab when I use python `Process`. I tried `print` function and `logging` module but it doesn't work.
This simple example produces output on my machine (jupyter notebook, python 3.6.9) but doesn't work in colab:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def simple_fun(proc_id):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(proc_id)
    
N_PROCESS = 2
processes = []
for i in range(N_PROCESS):
    p = Process(target=simple_fun, args=(i,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
```

Is there anything I can do?

Am I missing something? May be the code above is platform-depended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it doesn't work only when I doesn't wait for a process with `join` function.

I can't block all processes at once.

But if process work takes approximately the same amount of time for all processes than I can block only on one process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import logging

def simple_fun(proc_id):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        #logging.info(proc_id)
        print(proc_id)
    
N_PROCESS = 2
processes = []
for i in range(N_PROCESS):
    p = Process(target=simple_fun, args=(i,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

processes[0].join() # <- wait for one of processes
```

This one works.

Answer (score 1):

This process example works on google colab *(Python 3.6.9)*

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
        print( 'parent process:', os.getppid())
    print( 'process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: It works because you added `p.join()`. For some reason `print` works in usual jupyter notebook without `join` but doesn't work in google colab.